# "fail to set top app changed" error

Tags: android, debugging, crash, ddms

Can anyone help me to point out the flaws? I'm new to Android development and I don't really understand debugging with DDMS
Here's the DDMS error log:

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494): java.lang.NullPointerException

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1527)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.clarify.clarifycam.MusicLoad.loadMusic(MusicLoad.java:29)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.clarify.clarifycam.ClarifyCamera.onOptionsItemSelected(ClarifyCamera.java:572)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2202)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:739)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:545)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

10-13 16:07:51.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14494):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

10-13 16:07:52.724: ERROR/ActivityManager(96): fail to set top app changed!

Thanks in advance!